# How can I replace water valve in Liebherr fridge-freezer?

Tags: valve, ice-maker, freezer

I intend to check the water valve between the water tank that is in the refrigerator and the ice-maker that is in the freezer of my Liebherr ICN 3366. Where is this valve and how can I reach it?
How can I check this valve?
Many thanks for caring.

Answer (score 0):

I found a service manual for the ICN 3356 not sure how similar it is but is worth a try.

https://assi.lhg.liebherr.com/Serviceline/b2b/bab2b/Media/documents/SM/2013/17201303SM_en.pdf

Comment: Thanks for this service manual, though this model doesn't have an ice maker. My model is ICN3366.